# How to fetch fresh results with each request and no-cache strategy in Apollo GraphlQL and Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

We have a value that is different everytime it's requested, like a `nonce`. So we want to get that value freshly with each request. Somehow I can't get it to work with Apollo's Angular client.

My first idea was to use `watchQuery` with the `no-cache` strategy:

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({query: NONCE_QUERY, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'})
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response.data.nonce);
```

This works fine and I get the result.

But when I use this multiple times, like:

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({query: NONCE_QUERY, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'})
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response.data.nonce);

this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({query: NONCE_QUERY, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'})
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response.data.nonce);
```

… the value of `response.data.nonce` is the same.

When I wait for the first request to finish, like:

```
this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({query: NONCE_QUERY, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'})
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.data.nonce);

    this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({query: NONCE_QUERY, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'})
       .valueChanges
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(response => console.log(response.data.nonce);
  }
```

… it works as expected.

I also tried the same requests using `this.apollo.query` instead of `watchQuery` but with the same result.

This is the Apollo provider:

```
{
  provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
  useFactory: (httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<any> => {
    return {
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: httpLink.create({
        uri: 'URL',
        withCredentials: true,
      }),
      defaultOptions: {
        query: {
          fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
        }
      }
    };
  },
  deps: [HttpLink],
}
```

**How to make Apollo send a new request each time even though another one is pending?**

Comment: Could you use `query` instead of `watchQuery`? It feels like you may be misusing `watchQuery` where you want a plain query. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.watchQuery

Answer (score 0):

add the following config to defaultOptions in your apollo provider.

```
    watchQuery: {
     fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
     errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    },
    query: {
     fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
     errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make a difference. I also want to change the cache strategy **for a specific request only**. All other requests should rely on Apollo's caching.